# BigQuery check if table exists or not

Tags: c#, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm using C# to dynamically construct a query based on a response from the bigquery api tables endpoint. I'm trying to calculate active users which works, but only if I select every table with `.*`. My question is quite simple really, is there a way to check if a table exists within BigQuery SQL?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are metatables called `__TABLES__` and `__TABLES_SUMMARY__`

You can run a query like:

```
SELECT size_bytes FROM <dataset>.__TABLES__ WHERE table_id='mytablename'
```

The `__TABLES__` portion of that query may look unfamiliar. `__TABLES_SUMMARY__` is a meta-table containing information about tables in a dataset. You can use this meta-table yourself. For example, the query `SELECT * FROM publicdata:samples.__TABLES_SUMMARY__` will return metadata about the tables in the `publicdata:samples` dataset. You can also do `SELECT * FROM publicdata:samples.__TABLES__`

**Available Fields:**

The fields of the `__TABLES_SUMMARY__` meta-table (that are all available in the `TABLE_QUERY` query) include:

- `table_id`: name of the table.
- `creation_time`: time, in milliseconds since 1/1/1970 UTC, that the table was created. This is the same as the `creation_time` field on the table.
- `type`: whether it is a view (2) or regular table (1).

The following fields are *not* available in `TABLE_QUERY()` since they are members of `__TABLES__` but not `__TABLES_SUMMARY__`. They're kept here for historical interest and to partially document the `__TABLES__` metatable:

- `last_modified_time`: time, in milliseconds since 1/1/1970 UTC, that the table was updated (either metadata or table contents). Note that if you use the `tabledata.insertAll()` to stream records to your table, this might be a few minutes out of date.
- `row_count`: number of rows in the table.
- `size_bytes`: total size in bytes of the table.

Comment: I tried above query with BigQueryOperator for Airflow things, It's not working. So is there any way of implementation for BigQueryOperator. So we can check if_table_exist or not.

Answer (score 7):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM `project.dataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
WHERE table_id = 'mytable'
```

Comment: As a follow up, is it possible to check if a new table has been added to a shard table?

Comment: what is your definition for `new table`?

Comment: Eg: I have a dataset with tables named 'AB_timestamp'. So every week a new a table with the appropriate timestamp should be added. Would I be able to check that? I know I could manually check it but I am trying to automate it.

Comment: so, you want to (let's say) check if table for current week is already added?

Comment: Yes. Check if the table 'AB_timestamp' for a given timestamp has been added.

Comment: sure possible. format of comments does not allow properly present / format the answer - please post your question and I will answer it right away while I am in front of my pc :o)