# Conditional logic in BigQuery scripts

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to write a BigQuery statement / script which:

1. Checks if table_a exists
2. If table_a exists, select col_1, col_2, col_3 from table_a
3. If table_a does not exist, select col_1, col_2, col_3 from table_b

I know how to do step 1:

```
select count(1) cnt from `project.dataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
WHERE table_id = 'table_a'
```

thanks to this post:
[BigQuery check if table exists or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42859614/bigquery-check-if-table-exists-or-not)

However, I can't do the rest of it.  I have tried:

```
if (select count(1) cnt from `project.dataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
WHERE table_id = 'table_a')=1
select col_1, col_2, col_3 from table_a
```

And have also tried:

```
if (select count(1) cnt from `project.dataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
WHERE table_id = 'table_a')=1
then 
select col_1, col_2, col_3 from table_a
```

Both of these fail.
Is this sort of conditional logic outside of a select statement possible in standard SQL?

(obviously inside of a select clause, I could have used a case statement, but I don't see how that could be used here when I want to change the table to be queried, based on a condition.  And I could wrap the statement in Python code and put the condition there, but I am trying to avoid wrappers, as I wish to use the query as a saved view in BQ).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
DECLARE table_count int64;

set table_count = (select count(*) from dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name = 'table_a');

if table_count >= 1 then (select col_1,col_2,col_3 from dataset.table_a);
else (select col_1,col_2,col_3 from dataset.table_b);
end if;
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work, although it returns a list of two sets of results when I run it - one useless result for the "set table_count" and one desired result.  I need to manually click on "view results" for the final results, which makes this hard to plug into any sort of ETL or even a BQ view.  Sorry this is probably a dumb question - do you know how to only return the final result, without needing clicking into it?

Comment: I'm actually not sure; that might warrant a new question to ask about processing BQ scripting results.  For creating a view/table, you could probably put a `CREATE` statement inside the `if/else` logic, but I haven't tried it.